# How to increment a counter in spider if condition in pipelines is True ? [SCRAPY-PYTHON]

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, pipeline

I'm scraping items and using postal codes (cp) in the urls

```
def parse(self, response):
    liste = ['09', '81']
    for counter in range(len(liste)):
        cp = liste[counter]
        for i in range(0, 2):
            user_agent = random.choices(user_agent_list)
            headers = {

                'User-Agent': str(user_agent),
                "Connection": "close",
            }

         next_pagination_link ='https://www.seloger.com/list.htm?projects=2&types=1,2&places=[{cp:' + 
                               str(cp) + '}]&sort=d_dt_crea&enterprise=0&qsVersion=1.0&LISTING- 
                               LISTpg=' + str(i) + ''
```

In the pipilines.py, I'm using this script in the process_item method to drop existing items in the sql database:

```
    if record is None:
        print('storing item')
        self.store_db(item)
        return True
    elif record is not None:
        raise DropItem("Item already exists: %s" % item['lien_du_bien'])
```

What I want to do is: If an item is droped, I want to increment the variable counter in the spider by 1 in order to move to another postal code.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: you have access to the spider through the `process_item(self, item, spider)` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `def process_item(self, item, spider)` of you pipeline, you can do `spider.YOUR_SPIDER_VARIABLE` to access any of variable of your Spider

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if record is None:
        print('storing item')
        self.store_db(item)
        return True
    elif record is not None:
        spider.VARIABLE_TO_INCREMENT
        raise DropItem("Item already exists: %s" % item['lien_du_bien'])
```